# set the value of a dataframe by the minimum of a subgroup

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 3 columns, I would like to apply the worst of the subset to the parent in the hierarchy, the frame looks like this to start

```
df1 =

    contains_subsets    hierarchy        rank
0   1.0                 1.1              NaN
1   1.0                 2.11.3           NaN
2   NaN                 2.11.3.1         Good
3   NaN                 2.11.3.10        Warning
4   NaN                 2.11.3.11        Warning
5   NaN                 2.11.3.12        Good
6   1.0                 2.11.3.13        NaN
7   NaN                 2.11.3.13.1      Critical
8   NaN                 2.11.3.13.2      Critical
9   NaN                 2.11.3.13.3      Good
10  NaN                 2.11.3.13.4      Good
11  NaN                 2.11.3.13.5      Good
12  1.0                 2.11.3.14        NaN
13  NaN                 2.11.3.14.1      Warning
14  NaN                 2.11.3.14.11     Critical
15  NaN                 2.11.3.14.12     Warning
16  NaN                 2.11.3.14.13     Good
17  NaN                 2.11.3.14.14     Good
```

First thought is to convert rank to numeric, like so

```
dictionary = {'Good':3, 'Warning':2, 'Critical':1}

df1['Rank_Numeric'] = df1['rank'].map(dictionary)
df1

contains_subsets     hierarchy          rank  Rank_Numeric
0                1.0           1.1           NaN           NaN
1                1.0        2.11.3           NaN           NaN
2                NaN      2.11.3.1          Good           3.0
3                NaN     2.11.3.10       Warning           2.0
4                NaN     2.11.3.11       Warning           2.0
5                NaN     2.11.3.12          Good           3.0
6                1.0     2.11.3.13           NaN           NaN
7                NaN   2.11.3.13.1      Critical           1.0
8                NaN   2.11.3.13.2      Critical           1.0
9                NaN   2.11.3.13.3          Good           3.0
10               NaN   2.11.3.13.4          Good           3.0
11               NaN   2.11.3.13.5          Good           3.0
12               1.0     2.11.3.14           NaN           NaN
13               NaN   2.11.3.14.1       Warning           2.0
14               NaN  2.11.3.14.11      Critical           1.0
15               NaN  2.11.3.14.12       Warning           2.0
16               NaN  2.11.3.14.13          Good           3.0
17               NaN  2.11.3.14.14          Good           3.0
```

Then I thought I would split the hierarchy to group each subset by the parent like so

```
df1['parent'] = df1['hierarchy'].apply(lambda x: '.'.join(x.split('.')[:-1]))
print(df1)
contains_subsets     hierarchy          rank  Rank_Numeric     parent
0                1.0           1.1           NaN           NaN          1
1                1.0        2.11.3           NaN           NaN       2.11
2                NaN      2.11.3.1          Good           3.0     2.11.3
3                NaN     2.11.3.10       Warning           2.0     2.11.3
4                NaN     2.11.3.11       Warning           2.0     2.11.3
5                NaN     2.11.3.12          Good           3.0     2.11.3
6                1.0     2.11.3.13           NaN           NaN     2.11.3
7                NaN   2.11.3.13.1      Critical           1.0  2.11.3.13
8                NaN   2.11.3.13.2      Critical           1.0  2.11.3.13
9                NaN   2.11.3.13.3          Good           3.0  2.11.3.13
10               NaN   2.11.3.13.4          Good           3.0  2.11.3.13
11               NaN   2.11.3.13.5          Good           3.0  2.11.3.13
12               1.0     2.11.3.14           NaN           NaN     2.11.3
13               NaN   2.11.3.14.1       Warning           2.0  2.11.3.14
14               NaN  2.11.3.14.11      Critical           1.0  2.11.3.14
15               NaN  2.11.3.14.12       Warning           2.0  2.11.3.14
16               NaN  2.11.3.14.13          Good           3.0  2.11.3.14
17               NaN  2.11.3.14.14          Good           3.0  2.11.3.14
```

so now I have a value for hierarchy that corresponds to several values of parent, I want to apply the minimum rank of the children to the parent so it would look like so

```
contains_subsets     hierarchy          rank  Rank_Numeric     parent
0                1.0           1.1           NaN           NaN          1
1                1.0        2.11.3       Warning           2.0       2.11
2                NaN      2.11.3.1          Good           3.0     2.11.3
3                NaN     2.11.3.10       Warning           2.0     2.11.3
4                NaN     2.11.3.11       Warning           2.0     2.11.3
5                NaN     2.11.3.12          Good           3.0     2.11.3
6                1.0     2.11.3.13      Critical           1.0     2.11.3
7                NaN   2.11.3.13.1      Critical           1.0  2.11.3.13
8                NaN   2.11.3.13.2      Critical           1.0  2.11.3.13
9                NaN   2.11.3.13.3          Good           3.0  2.11.3.13
10               NaN   2.11.3.13.4          Good           3.0  2.11.3.13
11               NaN   2.11.3.13.5          Good           3.0  2.11.3.13
12               1.0     2.11.3.14      Critical           1.0     2.11.3
13               NaN   2.11.3.14.1       Warning           2.0  2.11.3.14
14               NaN  2.11.3.14.11      Critical           1.0  2.11.3.14
15               NaN  2.11.3.14.12       Warning           2.0  2.11.3.14
16               NaN  2.11.3.14.13          Good           3.0  2.11.3.14
17               NaN  2.11.3.14.14          Good           3.0  2.11.3.14
```

I tried doing this with a loc, but it didn't have the desired result

```
df1.loc[df1['hierarchy'] == df1['parent'], 'Rank_Numeric'] = df1['Rank_Numeric'].min()
this made no changes to the dataframe
```

then I tried creating a new column with the following logic to see if that would work

```
df1.loc[df1['hierarchy'] == df1['parent'], 'sub_min'] = df1['Rank_Numeric'].min()

print(df1)
    contains_subsets     hierarchy          rank  Rank_Numeric     parent   sub_min
0                1.0           1.1           NaN           NaN          1   NaN
1                1.0        2.11.3           NaN           NaN       2.11   NaN
2                NaN      2.11.3.1          Good           3.0     2.11.3   NaN
3                NaN     2.11.3.10       Warning           2.0     2.11.3   NaN
4                NaN     2.11.3.11       Warning           2.0     2.11.3   NaN
5                NaN     2.11.3.12          Good           3.0     2.11.3   NaN
6                1.0     2.11.3.13           NaN           NaN     2.11.3   NaN
7                NaN   2.11.3.13.1      Critical           1.0  2.11.3.13   NaN
8                NaN   2.11.3.13.2      Critical           1.0  2.11.3.13   NaN
9                NaN   2.11.3.13.3          Good           3.0  2.11.3.13   NaN
10               NaN   2.11.3.13.4          Good           3.0  2.11.3.13   NaN
11               NaN   2.11.3.13.5          Good           3.0  2.11.3.13   NaN
12               1.0     2.11.3.14           NaN           NaN     2.11.3   NaN
13               NaN   2.11.3.14.1       Warning           2.0  2.11.3.14   NaN
14               NaN  2.11.3.14.11      Critical           1.0  2.11.3.14   NaN
15               NaN  2.11.3.14.12       Warning           2.0  2.11.3.14   NaN
16               NaN  2.11.3.14.13          Good           3.0  2.11.3.14   NaN
17               NaN  2.11.3.14.14          Good           3.0  2.11.3.14   NaN
```

so that didn't work either, I'm not sure where to go from here

the logic so far is where hierarchy equals parent, assign the minimum ranking from the group with the same parent to the parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close. A groupby parent and a merge would do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'hierarchy':['0.1','1.1','1.2','1.1.1','1.1.2'], 'parent':['0','1','1','1.1','1.1'], 'rank':[1,2,3,4,5]})
```

```
    hierarchy   parent  rank
0   1          0        1
1   1.1        1        2
2   1.2        1        3
3   1.1.1      1.1      4
4   1.1.2      1.1      5
```

Step 1: find the worst rank corresponding to each parent

Step2: merge to the original DataFrame on hierarchy == parent

```
df_worst_rank = df.groupby(['parent'])[['rank']].min().reset_index().rename(columns={'rank':'worst_rank'})
df = df.merge(df_worst_rank, left_on = 'hierarchy', right_on = 'parent', how = 'left')
```

```
hierarchy   parent_x    rank    parent_y    worst_rank
0   1       0           1       1       2.0
1   1.1     1           2       1.1     4.0
2   1.2     1           3       NaN     NaN
3   1.1.1   1.1         4       NaN     NaN
4   1.1.2   1.1         5       NaN     NaN
```